# How to save a file to a local machine that you are editing via SSH

Tags: ssh

Here is my situation:

At work I have to ssh into a server from various different machines.  I frequently need to update the file on the remote machine but also save a copy locally (on whichever machine at work I am using).

I usually use emacs on the server I have ssh into but not always.

Is there a direct way to save the file I edited while ssh'd into the server on my local machine?  I.e. pipe it to my local machine somehow?

Comment: Why do you need this? Maybe we can help with some alternative solutions.

Comment: @msfoster I edited the question, should be clear now.

Comment: -Then you can use secure copy `scp`. I don't believe you have other options. Make an alias or a script to do this job easier.